# Not able to get or set values to a newly added column - MySQL with Hibernates

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a strange issue that when I try to add a new column to MySQL table and try to read the value from Hibernate JPA getter, the result is NULL always. But it works for other tables, only specific table has issue. Here is what i did -

1. Altered a table to add new column and inserted values, the Hibernate JPA getter method returns NULL.
2. Didn't alter table instead directly modified the Hibernate JPA model in java class and could see a NEW column added in MYSQL, but still the values from getter method is NULL again.
3. Tried above steps with another table, it works fine.

Example:

```
@Column(name = "plandate")
private Date plandate;

public Date getPlandate() {
    return plandate;
}

public void setPlandate(Date plandate) {
    this.plandate = plandate;
}
```

`getPlandate()` returns always `NULL`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure plandate is not null in database?

Comment: SQL issued by your JPA provider is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.(if your column "plandate" is of data type "datetime")

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "plandate")
private Date plandate;

public Date getPlandate() {
    return plandate;
}
```

(else if your column "plandate" is of data type "date")

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "plandate")
private Date plandate;

public Date getPlandate() {
    return plandate;
}
public void setPlandate(Date plandate) {
    this.plandate = plandate;
}
```